# How to validate data from new return data value feature stored in block header

Tags: eosjs

How would one go about validating the data from the block header of a return data value action?  It seems like a cool feature, but you'd need a full history node to validate wouldn't you?

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In block header, you can find `action_mroot`. `action_mroot` is the root hash of merkle tree of `action_receipt`s. `action_receipt` contains `act_digest`, and `act_digest` is constructed by hashing `action` itself and `action_return_value`.

You can validate `action_return_value` by comparing the hash value (of action and its return value) and `act_digest` in action receipt.

```
// eos/libraries/chain/apply_context.cpp

act_digest = generate_action_digest(
  [this](const char* data, uint32_t datalen) {
    return trx_context.hash_with_checktime<digest_type>(data, datalen);
  },
  *act,
  action_return_value // here
);
```